# Вставить значения

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Из базы данных

```
$phone=$row["phone"];
$email=$row["email"];
$stroka=$row["stroka"]; // ее содержание - У Вас номер телефона $phone, а почта $email";
```

Как вставить значения $phone и $email в $stroka?

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать заменить плейсхолдеры. Никакой гарантии отсутствия коллизий.

```
$phone = '555-35-35';
$email = 'no@example.org';
$stroka = 'Email: $email; Phone: $phone';

$stroka = strtr($stroka, array('$email' => $email, '$phone' => $phone));

echo $stroka;
```

[strtr](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strtr.php)

Comment: А так `$stroka = "Email: $email; Phone: $phone";` уже не работает что ли?  Зачем тут `strtr()`?

Comment: @Visman, потому что, как я понимаю, шаблон текста с "долларами-переменными" хранится в базе)

Answer (score 0):

Если просто в переменную $stroka то:
`$stroka = " У Вас номер телефона " . $phone . ", а почта " . $email`

Если нужно изменить значение в массиве то:
`$row["stroka"] = " У Вас номер телефона " . $phone . ", а почта " . $email`